# Wider caption for listing using multicol

Tags: listings, captions, multicol

I am using the `multicol` and `listings` packages. I would like to have the caption spread across the entire listing for multi-column listings.

Here is a MWE of what I am attempting, however the output is undesirable because the caption gets placed in the first column only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A longer caption that ideally spans all the columns in the listing, otherwise it just does not look right if you get what I mean}, multicols=3]

text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important

text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using explicitly the `multicols` environment (instead of the `multicols` key); the caption is typeset using `\captionof` from the `caption` package, using the optional argument of `multicols`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}[\captionof{lstlisting}{A longer caption that ideally spans all the columns in the listing, otherwise it just does not look right if you get what I mean}]
\begin{lstlisting}

text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important

text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important
text not important

\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well. Thanks - doing it this way did not occur to me!